# Laravel [ErrorException: Array to string conversion] database seeding

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a blog section on my website project
I am trying to seed the database but I am getting this error in the console:

```
root@ServerName:/var/www/laravel# php artisan db:seed --class=ArticlesSeeder

   ErrorException 

  Array to string conversion
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:675
    671▕ 
    672▕         $result = array_shift($segments);
    673▕ 
    674▕         foreach ($segments as $segment) {
  ➜ 675▕             $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    676▕         }
    677▕ 
    678▕         return $result;
    679▕     }

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   database/seeders/ArticlesSeeder.php:44
      Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()

      +23 vendor frames 
  33  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

This is the seeder file for the article tables.
ArticleSeeder.php:

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ArticlesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('articles')->truncate();

        $articles = [];

        foreach (range(1, 100) as $index)
        {
            $articles[] = [
                "slug"     => $slug = "article_$index",
                "catagory" => "category_$index",
                "title"    => "Title of $slug",
                "author"   => "$slug@remissiondigital.com",
                "body"    => "This isn't the \"real\" body of the $slug article\r\n
                                Here is more body\r\n
                                And more here too\r\n\r\n
                                just a seeder\r\n
                                more text",
                "created_at" => Carbon::now(),
                "updated_at" => [NULL],
                "deleted_at" => [NULL],
            ];
        }
        DB::table('articles')->insert($articles);
    }
}
```

This is default database seeder with a call towards the ArticlesSeeder
DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(ArticlesSeeder::class);

        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();

        // \App\Models\User::factory()->create([
        //     'name' => 'Test User',
        //     'email' => 'test@example.com',
        // ]);
    }
}
```

Here is the migration file for the articles table, I am not sure if the issue is the `$table->text('body');` but it seemed to me like the right way to sure the article body, and if you look up to seed it I tried this code

```
"body"    => "This isn't the \"real\" body of the $slug article\r\n
        Here is more body\r\n
        And more here too\r\n\r\n
        just a seeder\r\n
        more text",
```

2022_05_25_172508_create_articles.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('catagory')->nullable();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestampsTz($precision = 0);
            $table->softDeletesTz();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
};
```

Comment: You try to use a string function (`.=`) on an array, you can't do that.

Comment: @geertjanknapen That's in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php which is part of the laravel framework, not my creation.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it won't work on an array.

Comment: The error is from a typo, using and array with a null element inside it `"updated_at" => [NULL],` instead of setting it to null `"updated_at" => null,`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured out the issue minutes after I posted this.

If you want to post a null value while seeding:

Just don't write anything.

I removed these two lines and it worked

```
// "updated_at" => [NULL],
// "deleted_at" => [NULL],
```

Now it got a 100 entries in the database. :)

```
root@RemissionDigital:/var/www/laravel# php artisan db:seed --class=ArticlesSeeder
Database seeding completed successfully.
```

Comment: Created at or updated at are never required fields when creating models, they will always be created automatically

Comment: @OskarMikael I just learned that I thought you had to seed every line you made even if it's null.

Comment: @Tariq you can set it to null in the array with `"updated_at" => null` or you can set it to the right value `"updated_at" => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s')`